# Replacing faulty fan on CPU heatsink, minimum recommended air displacement

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

I woke up this morning with a broken fan on my CPU. The heatsink itself is a scythe Kabuto. The fan can be replaced quite easily at is a standard 120 mm fan. Now I'm not seeking for specific information in regard to what fan I should buy specifically, I'm seeking to know:

- recommended minimum air displacement
- Most effective, push or pull the air through the heatsink

Comment: I'm going to guess this will be hard to answer as it could be very system set up dependant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [scythe website](http://www.scythe-usa.com/product/cpu/042/sckbt1000_detail.html#specifications) the displacement on the stock fan is  "0 - 126 m³/h = 0 - 74.25 CFM" so anything of that rating or better would be fine

As for push vs pull - some people have tried experiments

From the tom's [hardware forums](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/335129-28-push-pull-tested) "Push offers 2C-4C difference in performance when compared to Pull."

And [from OCN](http://www.overclock.net/t/1292456/1-fan-vs-2-chapter-2-push-vs-pull)

"The slower fans won't cool this chip at that OC, so I could only use the fastest three pairs of fans, but the results are clear: at high overclock the pull-only fan does not cool as well as the push-only fan."

Small sample but generally a push fan is a better idea - pulling air over a heatsink is only useful in a 2 fan setup.

There's other things to consider - noise levels, other features (I'd prefer fans with no LEDS!) and bearing types (sleeves are the best, there's also roller bearings and other sorts, this affects noise levels and longevity). Some fans also have higher static pressure (for liquid cooling, but may be a better option for pushing air over a heatsink too) and such.

Depending on the position of the heatsink and your headroom, the *thickness* of the fan may be a factor too. Nothing worse than realising your fan won't fit where you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an answer re air displacement, but regarding push/pull - the key is to aim the air *out* of the box, (usually) towards the rear fan.
So depending on orientation, push the air if you position the fan on the far side of the heatsink, pull the air if the fan is positioned between the heatsink and the rear fan, or do both for maximum air displacement :-)

If you were asking, using a single fan which is more effective - close side with pull, or further side with push - then I would say that it matters less than other considerations. For example, in my case the height of the memory sticks (their own heatsink) combined with the width of the CPU heatsink, meant my choices were limited anyway...